# Java send request encoding

Tags: java, http, encoding

I'm trying to send get request in java, when it's without headers as below, I get redirected to login page.

```
 URL myURL1 = new URL("http://www.eventlister.com");
 URL obj = new URL(url);
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
 con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

But when request is sent with all headers as it is sent from browser when reading response I get it encoded like this
`???}isI??g)b?CZ?n?7BH?:m?u??dkzz;   $P????C2?????YT??;??B3m????7/?.o~?p,?????...`, even if encoding is set manually in reader.

```
URL myURL1 = new URL("http://www.eventlister.com");
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2,uk;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2,fr-FR;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2");
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
con.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
con.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.eventlister.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what is your question now?

Comment: the eventlister page is yours or other?

Comment: I want to get requested page in readable encoding

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's gzip'ed data. Try it without "Accept-Encoding: gzip", so that server returns plain data.

I know this is a comment, not an answer. I don't have comment privilege yet :-(